# 404 ERROR POST Request and No Output for GET Request in Java Servlet

Tags: java, json, post, servlets, get

Screenshot ->  [image]
[image]

```
package com.example;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

@WebServlet("/Get")
public class Get extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Get() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        String apiUrl = "http://localhost:8080/Backendtest/Get";

        HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(apiUrl);

        // Set headers
        httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet);
            int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                if (httpEntity != null) {
                    InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

                    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8")) {
                        String jsonString = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();

                        // Parse JSON using Jackson ObjectMapper
                        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonString);

                        System.out.println("Received JSON response:");
                        System.out.println(jsonNode.toPrettyString());

                        // Set response content type and write the JSON response
                        response.setContentType("application/json");
                        response.getWriter().write(jsonNode.toPrettyString());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Handle non-200 status code (e.g., 404)
                response.setStatus(statusCode);
                response.getWriter().write("Error: Received non-200 status code: " + 
            statusCode);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Handle exceptions (e.g., network errors)
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            response.getWriter().write("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        String apiUrl = "http://localhost:8080/Backendtest/Post"; // Replace with the 
        correct POST endpoint URL

        HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(apiUrl);

        // Set headers
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        // Create a JSON payload to send in the request body
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode requestData = objectMapper.createObjectNode()
                .put("key1", "value1")
                .put("key2", "value2");

        // Convert the JSON payload to a string and set it as the request body
        StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(requestData.toString());
        httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);

        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
            int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Handle the successful response as you did before
                // ...
            } else if (statusCode == 404) {
                // Handle the 404 error
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
                response.getWriter().write("Error: The requested resource was not found (404)");
            } else {
                // Handle other non-200 status codes
                response.setStatus(statusCode);
                response.getWriter().write("Error: Received non-200 status code: " + statusCode);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Handle exceptions (e.g., network errors)
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            response.getWriter().write("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    
}
```

1. For the given java servlet , I tried to execute the localhost url on Postman app to generate output on GET Request in java console and Upon Post request there should be json displayed in POSTMAN app.
2. The Error 404 occurs on POSTMAN app upon Post request.
3. No output is generated in java console for Get request.
4. Screenshot uploaded for the given errors
5. Please help me fix the error in the java code.

Comment: The URL must match the value of @WebServlet. See abovelinked duplicate.

Comment: But I am trying to work upon the url Api endpoints

Comment: Wait, you wanted to let the servlet invoke itself in an infinite loop? Why? Did you at all understand the comment *"// Replace with the correct POST endpoint URL"*